# qt 5 looking for API-MS-WINxx.dll using GDAL headers

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2010, dll, gdal

I am developing a C++ Software with OpenCV 3.1 and QT 5 under win7 64Bit System.
The uses compiler is the VS2010 32bit.

I have to use another lib, called GDAL. I built this lib, set PATH environment and set the project properties in QT. As soon as I include a single .h file of GDAL the developed program starts and the instantly ends. QT gives messages like “debugging started” “debugging ended”.

Set break points won’t be reached so the program  isn’t even starting. The GDAL lib seems to be included correctly because the used GDAL variables and classes are indicated by the autocomplete function of QT.

I used dependency walker to see if some dll are not loaded. This tools tells me that the following dlls are missing. These dll don’t exist on the harddrive.

```
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-1.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-DEBUG-L1-1-1.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-DELAYLOAD-L1-1-1.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-1.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-1.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-1.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-L1-2-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-JOB-L2-1-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-LEGACY-L1-1-1.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-2-1.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-OBSOLETE-L1-2-0.DLL`enter code here`
```

One dll called GPSVC.dll was downloaded  from the web.  I have read  several threads that people have same issues. Some have been fixing these issues by installing redistributable packages. I have  all available redistributable packages installed and VS2010 ultimate.

I am getting sick of this problem, does anyone have THE solution to fix? What programs are associated with these listed dlls.

Would downgrading of QT 5 to QT 4 solve the problem.

I haven’t found threads with these issues when QT 4 is used. 
Any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks

**edit:**
just to make all this clear, I would like to give you an overview of my settings.
the windows Path variable looks like this:

```
E:\opencv31\build\install\x86\vc10\bin;

C:\Qt5\5.5\msvc2010\bin;
E:\GDAL\bin
```

the .pro file of the qt project:
     QT       += core gui
     greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
    TARGET = AirportExtractor
    TEMPLATE = app

```
SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp \
imageanalyzer.cpp \
airport.cpp \
filterslider.cpp \
framewindows.cpp \
scribblearea.cpp \
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
imageanalyzer.h \
airport.h \
filterslider.h \
framewindows.h \
scribblearea.h \
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
filterslider.ui \
framewindows.ui \

INCLUDEPATH += E:/GDAL/include/
INCLUDEPATH += E:/opencv31/build/install/include/ 

LIBS += -LE:/opencv31/build/install/x86/vc10/lib -lopencv_calib3d310d \
-LE:/GDAL/lib -lgdal_i \
```

I  added the following paths to the project settings:

```
INCLUDE E:\GDAL\include;
LIB E:\GDAL\lib;
```

Comment: The `API-MS-WIN-CORE-*` missing dlls are not a problem. The correct dlls will exist.

Comment: It sounds like the GDAL dll is not in your system path or is incompatible with the GDAL that Qt was compiled with.

Comment: I think I didn't have to compile qt. I just used the installer. Gdal was compiled by the msvs 2010 nmake console. This was the only way to build it since there are no cmake files available. Gdal was installed after qt. But path variables are set!

Comment: @drescherjm I have edited my 1st post with all my settings. Please check above,

Comment: OK guys, I got it running. I copied the gdal.dll into the debug dir. There was also some bug in the code.The dependency walker did not point to the right solution because these dlls are not really necessary.